# Android: How can I do this popup menu (spinner or something else?)

Tags: android, popup, spinner

[image]

I don't understand. Is it spinner, popup or clickabel custom layout?
I tried to make spinner. Created the adapter with getView and getDropDownView, but I don't understand how to make margins before the first element and after last. Also it isn't clear how insert in the middle a divider that the clickabel area of items also had an margin from a divider. As in the drawing.
Gray items - pressed.
Also i have tried custom spinner style

```
<item name="android:paddingTop">8dp</item>
<item name="android:paddingBottom">8dp</item>
```

spaces from above and from below have appeared, but it seems to me, it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you need something like Spinner with more options you can use [ListPopupWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/ListPopupWindow.html) which you can customize by extending a adapter with multiple types of items/xml.

Or just create [PopupWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) looks like you want and [show it as drop down](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#showAsDropDown(android.view.View)).